# how to work with Git merge and update my working directory?

Tags: git

I download the last version from the server with

`git fetch`

as far as I understood now the repository is updated.

I have two questions :

1. Now I worked on file that was changed from the server and I want to do the merge ?
   when Do I need to do the merge ? Do I need to do it after the git fetech or when I do the add files ? could you please exaplain me what should be the statmentes for the merge process ?
2. If I want to update my workign directory and I don't have any merge How I can do it ?
   I tried to do it with  :

   `git checkout -f "mybranch"`
   `git rebase`
   `git checkout "mybranch"`

is it ok ? Do I have different way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't merge in this case.  If I have outstanding changes, I do

```
git stash
git checkout master #if I'm not on master
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git checkout whateverbranh #if I was not on master
git rebase master #if I was not on master
git stash pop
```

I think a lot of people don't do this; I like it because it keeps my history line linear.

You can't always avoid a merge.  In this case, if files have changed on the server, and my commits have changed those same files, I have to resolve the conflicts during the rebase.

Comment: what is the meaning of stash? what will happen in this scenario ?

Comment: i saves all your uncommitted changes in a stash.  When you pop the stash, git reapplies those changes.

Comment: How the stash help you in this case ?in the end you replace the old version ?

Answer (score 1):

The most common workflow is

```
git pull 
# do something useful
git commit
git push
```

`pull` is just `fetch` and `merge` (means: merging `remoteName/branchName` into `branchName`) and in most cases sufficient.

Comment: Can I use fetch and not pull ? the merge is only when I get files from the server and not when I upload ?

Comment: You can use `fetch`, but then the changes are not merged into your "local branches" [1]. This is useful, when you want to fetch a branch, that you don't "know" yet (`fetch origin anotherBranch`,`checkout -b anotherBranch origin/anotherBranch`). If you push changes the remote on merge your changes into it's branch(es). You usually should not need to take care about it. ([1] Every branch is local of course, but some represents the remote branches)

Comment: Do I need to add new branch when I use pull ? for example my branch is branch1 do I need to git pull to new branch or to the same branch ? IF I have two files with the same issue does in the pull I will got error of merge ?and then I will need to use some statement of merge